# NSMutableDictionary with accent

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am working with NSMutableDictionary and in this array I am using words with accent and to add this work, fine. The problem is to retrieve and work with.

To add:
    [dicPT_SP setObject:@"São Paulo" forKey:@"São Paulo"];

When retrieving, I am getting:
    "S\U00e3o Paulo"

How can I solve this issue? I think it is simple, however I cant find a solution googling.
Any idea is very welcome.

Comment: Realize that NSLog converts "odd" characters to escaped notation.  `\U00e3` is "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE".

Comment: If be retrieving you mean using NSLog to view it, you will see this with dictionaries and arrays containing such strings. If you access the string directly it should display nicer.

Comment: That is correct, I dont need to worry about accent. When I need to access the array (any one) will give me the correct value. The NSLog function made me believe it was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to encode this string first...This is unicode string which you are getting.
You need to encode that to UTF8 string like this.

```
char cString[] = "This isn\u2019t your bike";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result string: %@", string);
```

OR

```
NSString *input = @"\\u5404\\u500b\\u90fd";
    NSString *convertedString = [input mutableCopy];
    CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
    CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);
    NSLog(@"convertedString: %@", convertedString);
```

Comment: Perfect, I didnt need to do anything in my code, the Foundation already takes care of the enconding, but your answer was very good because NSLog doesnt ... and took me to think it was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderBurbello always welcome...NSLog doesn't do it...So you need to take care of that. That code was for your NSlog statements, as you can see the NSLog in my code example..Rest was up to you...Cheers